# Install python-Levenshtein on AWS (lambda) to speed up fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using fuzzywuzzy on Amazon Aws Lambda. I get the following error:

warnings.warn('Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning')

I don't have this problem on my local pc because I have:
    pip install python-Levenshtein

But how to do this on AWS Lambda?

I know python-Levenshtein uses C, and that seems to be the problem. Is there a way to do so? If so, can you provide step by step instructions?

I have added python-Levenshtein in my deployment package.

But it doesn't seem to prevent the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, AWS Lambda has issues deploying packages that are not pure Python but work with extension modules. 
You will have to make sure that your code is compiled for Linux. 
Perhaps the following guide can help you: https://markn.ca/2018/02/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/

Comment: Really useful guide. Thanks.

Comment: I had to go to the wayback machine to get this: https://web.archive.org/web/20181220154605/https://markn.ca/2018/02/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/

Comment: Current live URL: https://markn.ca/2018/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/